# Owin.Providers yahoo FantasySports API Access Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, oauth, owin, yahoo-api

Very hard to understand how to use Oauth or OWIN for anything besides logging in.  I have created an MVC web app.  I can have users log into my app using their Yahoo ID (instead of a local ID) just fine.  This is done using Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo

I can also make API calls using DevDefinedOauth, here is a code snippet:

```
public ActionResult Test2(string oauth_token, string oauth_verifier)
        {
            if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth_token))
            {
                oauthButton_Click();
            }
            else
            {
                OAuthSession session = (OAuthSession)Session["oAuthSession"];
                IToken requestToken = (IToken)Session["oAuthToken"];
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(oauth_verifier))
                {
                    IToken accessToken = session.ExchangeRequestTokenForAccessToken(requestToken, oauth_verifier);
                    Session["oAuthSession"] = session;
                }
            }

            IConsumerRequest playerData = ((OAuthSession)Session["oAuthSession"]).Request().Get().ForUrl("http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/371/players");
            var xml = playerData.ToDocument();
```

My problem is I want to eliminate the use of DevDefinedOauth (if possible) and use only Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo

I cannot find any documentation out there on how to use Owin to do this.  Is it possible?  I noticed I can try something like this, but it yields no results:

```
var token = new Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo.Messages.AccessToken();
            string test = token.Token;
```

I read a post on how to get the access token if you use facebook and Oauth, but the same code doesn't work for Yahoo.  I am not sure if there is something that needs to be added to my Startup Class, or my Account controller action (below).

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public async Task<ActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
        {
            var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
            if (loginInfo == null)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login");
            }

            // Sign in the user with this external login provider if the user already has a login
            var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(loginInfo.Login);
            if (user != null)
            {
                await SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                //var client  = new Owin.Security.Providers.Yahoo.
                return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
            }
            else
            {
                // If the user does not have an account, then prompt the user to create an account
                ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
                ViewBag.LoginProvider = loginInfo.Login.LoginProvider;
                return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new ExternalLoginConfirmationViewModel { UserName = loginInfo.DefaultUserName });
            }
        }
```

As you can see, if you look at my other posts, I am a little lost.   I feel like I'm very close to the answer but just can't find it.  Woirst case scenario I can use Owin Providers for logging in and then use DevDefinedOauth for API calls but it seems like a lot fo extra code (and usings) for nothing.  If anyone has any ideas please let me know....